# jQuery datepicker not appearing in asp.net textbox controller

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, datepicker

Below is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#myDate').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

And I am creating the asp.net controller as below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

However, when I click on the textbox, nothing happens and the datepicker window does not appear.

Comment: You didn't include the jquery ui javascript file

Comment: @Mivaweb can you please elaborate? I did not get you.

Comment: @JamesRonalde you have included the jquery library and the jquery ui css stylesheet but not the jquery ui library file

Comment: @Mivaweb can you please post an answer?

Comment: View my answer with the solution

Comment: Easiest way that you can get it working is by using a cssClass rather than control ID, when the webpage loads it is converted into HTML which will change the control ID.

Answer (score 3):

> Jquery code is client side code, but **ASP:Textbox** is server side control (your textbox id is "**myDate**" which is on server side), but when its convert into HTML it can change its id like as "**ContenPlaceHolder_myDate**", so "myDate" id will not found on client side, to resolve this problem we can use **ClientID** which resolve server side control id into client side control (HTML control).

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            $('#<%=myDate.ClientID %>').datepicker();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Try this is not enough. Explain what you have done so that the OP can understand this!

Comment: i think i was missing # , now check

Answer (score 0):

myDate is a server control here. So you can not access this by what you have written in the jquery code so check the below jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= myDate.ClientID %>").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Explain what you have done so that the OP understand what you are doing here.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't include the correct library to use the `datepicker` plugin.

[Example jQuery Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

You need to add following in your head tag:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Also you are using ASP.NET so your ID can be quite different.
Look at the answer of Durgesh Pandey for this.

You can see that you need to take the `ClientID` of your input field.

Comment: I added this but it does not work :/ still nothing shows

Comment: nothing. there is no error. it just doesnt do anything when you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not be the solution for you if you want to assign `datepicker` by control's ID. But it could be easier to use `CssClass` attribute of Control if you don't want to get confused by ID (serverside) and ID when rendered to HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('.datePickerClass').datepicker();
    });
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="myDate" runat="server" CssClass="datePickerClass"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you should change "datepicker" by "datetimepicker" and assign a format if u want just the day

Comment: Datepicker is an existing plugin in jquery ui